# How can an app decide whether the device is trusted or not?

Tags: security, permissions

I downloaded the trustable app from the play store which identifies whether the phone is trusted or not.

I run the application and it gave me a score of 4.3 with a suspicious.

Is this a genuine issue or just an other spam application. If it's true then what do I need to make it a trusted device.

Comment: Instead of using such apps, install a popular antivirus app like 360 Security. It is a well-trusted app that scans for vulnerabilities and fixes them too, unlike the Trustable app which just gives a score.

Comment: Sounds pretty gimmicky even if it does check for known vulnerabilities and such.

Comment: I just tried it on my Nexus 5 running Lollipop 5.1 (rooted), and I got 8.6 (trustable). It seems valid given the details (e.g. "unknown source" is enabled, many 3rd-parties app installed). I'd say "don't take the score too seriously". Instead, try your best to fix the issues told in the app.

Comment: Also, [this](https://bluebox.com/blog/technical/measuring-mobile-security-trust-introducing-trustable-by-bluebox/) and [this](https://bluebox.com/trustable-by-bluebox/) from BlueBox itself, though [something like this also happened](https://bluebox.com/blog/technical/popular-xiaomi-phone-could-put-data-at-risk/)